# Using a C# COM interface in Java

Tags: java, c#, android, com

I want to develop a Android App that gets data from a database. I will also develop this database and fill it with data from an API. Unfortuntely this API only provides a COM Interface and there documentation (http://www.tai-pan.net/produkte/tpr/index.aspx , sorry it's only in German but I guess you can look at the code) only shows how to use it in C#. 
I don't have any experience in C# or using COM interfaces so I don't know how I could access it from my server to read the data and put it into my database.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Obviously COM interface will not work on Android

Comment: The code there only shows that you can iterate some loops and that some objects have some properties. Is this an API for some netchange thing or does it generate all data locally?

Comment: It is used to to get financial data from this service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use C++ for this. Write a c++ code, which will interact with c# com and will get the data from COM and then pass this data to java.
In java you can interact with c++ or c program easily using JNI. 
You can use c++ with both of the languages.